# OSX - android sdk manager wouldn't open due to missing library

Tags: android

After I downloaded the android sdk for mac and tried to open(tools/android), the following exceptions thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseIniFileImpl(AvdManager.java:1748)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseIniFile(AvdManager.java:1667)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1452)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1435)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:343)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:353)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:252)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:120)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:407)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

I suppose that it misses the some libraries, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: did you figure this out?